# Kernel module warning

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to build a linux kernel module individually from linux kernel open source.

Source file is mm/ksm.c.

But problems happened below

```
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic/ M=/home/wei/module  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/wei/module/ksm.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "munlock_vma_page" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "follow_page_mask" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "page_remove_rmap" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "mm_find_pmd" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__page_check_address" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "anon_vma_interval_tree_iter_next" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__mmu_notifier_change_pte" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "ptep_clear_flush" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "page_address_in_vma" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "alloc_pages_vma" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "page_add_anon_rmap" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "try_to_free_swap" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "lru_add_drain_all" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "linear_hugepage_index" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "anon_vma_interval_tree_iter_first" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "split_huge_page_to_list" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "handle_mm_fault" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "mlock_vma_page" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "__put_anon_vma" [/home/wei/module/ksm.ko] undefined!
  CC      /home/wei/module/ksm.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/wei/module/ksm.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic'
```

I can't resolve even I insert `EXPORT_SYMBOL(fun);` in each header file.

How can I resolve this WARNING ?

Comment: These symbols **are not exported from the kernel core**. You cannot make them accessible for module with modifying headers - you need to modify kernel sources and recompile kernel. Normally, if you want to use many of non-exported symbols, you are better to add your functionality **directly** into kernel itself(by modifying its sources and recompiling it) instead of creating external module.

Comment: Thanks for your advice : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to compile parts of the kernel code as modules is to run `make menuconfig` and select the compilation as module. Alternatively, this can be even done by manually editing the `.config` file. Manually compiling the modules of parts of the kernel is discouraged, because it adds unnecessary work.

In addition, you have to know that **not all parts of the kernel can be compiled as modules**: the kernel core (i.e., memory management, scheduler, etc.) has not been designed to be compiled as a loadable kernel module.

Now, concerning your specific issue, you are compiling a file related to memory management. If you look at the `mm/Makefile` and `mm/Kconfig` files, you see that this file cannot be compiled as module.

Comment: I had seen the option in  menuconfig.
But "KSM" this feature cannot be selected to "M".
So I try to build it from linux source code.

Comment: The reason why "M" couldn't be selected is that it's a core component and therefore it's not been designed to be compiled as module.

Comment: I'm doubt that why Redhat's paper say "KSM is a Linux Kernel module"